# How to remove data from a recycled list view item

Tags: android

I'm using a custom list view adapter with **a)** view recycling and **b)** a view holder object.

I also successfully implemented an asynchronous image loader class to load bit maps to the list view for a smoother scrolling experience.

The problem now looks like the recycling, and correct if I'm wrong, but from a visual stand point it looks like the recycling is displaying previously loaded bit maps before the new ones are loaded such that there is a brief but noticeable flicker between the old image being replaced by the new one.

I hadn't noticed this effect before with the text views. Is this a recycling problem? Is there a way to scrape the old bit maps when the list item exits the visible screen area?

And yes, I am aware there are 3rd party libraries that account for all these effects. If I can't solve this problem by hand, then I will look into a library.

This is my list adapter

```
    // Get the data item for this position
    SongObject songObject = list.get(position);

    // view lookup cache stored in tag
    ViewHolder viewHolder; 

    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Set view holder references

    viewHolder.album = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.album);
    viewHolder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
    viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    viewHolder.albumArt = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.album_art);
    viewHolder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

    // Set values to referenced view objects

    viewHolder.album.setText(songObject.album);
    viewHolder.artist.setText(songObject.artist);
    viewHolder.title.setText(songObject.title);
    viewHolder.duration.setText(FormatTime(songObject.duration));

    // Load album art asynchronously for smoother scrolling experience

    new ImageLoader(viewHolder.albumArt).execute(songObject.albumArtURI);

    // Return the converted view

    return convertView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use recyclerView? Can you add code of recyclerViewAdapter implementation?

onBindViewHolder is a place where you should 'tune' you previously used (or not used)  viewHolder before giving it to user